# Get all Valid time slices in a Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scd

I have a table in which the entries are historized with SCD 2
Now I am looking for a possibility to get Alle PK 
which are valid at the same time:

For example my table Look like this:

```
PK;ValidFrom;ValidTo
635582110901;2016-01-04;2016-01-21
635582110901;2016-01-22;2016-01-26
635582110901;2016-01-27;2016-02-14
635582110901;2016-02-15;2016-11-10
**635582110901;2016-11-11;2017-01-23**
**635582110901;2016-11-16;2016-12-12**
635582110901;2016-12-13;2017-01-18
635582110901;2017-01-19;2017-01-22
635582110901;2017-01-23;2017-01-23
635582110901;2017-01-24;2017-02-21
635582110901;2017-02-22;9999-12-31
```

The select should give me the two bold Rows

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.validfrom < t.validto and
                    t2.validto > t.validfrom and
                    t2.pk = t.pk and
                    t2.validfrom <> t.validfrom and
                    t2.validto <> t.validto
             );
```

Comment: are you sure? So I select all the 11 recors

Comment: @AmBlack . . . I'm sure now.  I left out two other important conditions in my focus on the time overlap:  (1) The primary keys have to be the same; (2) A record overlaps with itself.  If records have exact duplicates, this will not find them.

Comment: Thank you very much! I agree with you in points 1 and 2. the bad record in this case is this with ValidFrom 20161111 and ValidTo 20170123, do you have a idee how to update all this bad guys? and set de validTo to (in this case) 15.11.16 ?

Comment: @AmBlack . . . That is a different question, and questions should be asked as *new* questions rather than in a comment.  If you are tempted to edit this question, don't.  You are likely to invalidate this answer, which in turn can draw downvotes.